Extract attribute from root element with Cheerio
Assume the following HTML:
const html = `
    <div id="base">
        <div lang="en"> .... </div>
    </div>`;
let $ = cheerio.load(html, null, false)
const base$ = $('#base')
const lang = base$.attr('lang') // -> Returns undefined

When I log the output from base$.html() with Cheerio I get:
<div lang="en"> .... </div>

Why can't I query this attribute? I've tried base$[0], $(base$), base$.eq(0) and base$.get(0)!.attribs.lang without any luck.

base$ is the outer div, with id="base". It does not have a lang attribute. If you want to query by some attribute use [name="value"], not #id.

So base$.html() only shows me its children. Given that base$.children()[0].attribs.lang seems to work I guess thats about right

It's the inner HTML: https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/classes/Cheerio#html, https://api.jquery.com/html/

#base is the outer <div> and has no lang attribute. You need to select the inner <div> which has the lang attribute on it:
import cheerio from "cheerio"; // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<div id="base"><div lang="en">...</div></div>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html, null, false);
const lang = $("#base [lang]").attr("lang");
console.log(lang); // => en

or any of the following probably less optimal approaches (for illustration):
$("#base > div").attr("lang");
$("#base > :first-child").attr("lang");
$("#base > *")[0].attribs.lang;
$("#base").find("[lang]").attr("lang");
$($("#base").children()[0]).attr("lang");
$("#base > *").first().attr("lang");
$("#base > *").eq(0).attr("lang");
$([...$("#base > *")][0]).attr("lang");

